# jQuery UI dialog boxes won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following code to open a dialog box:

```
<li>
     <input type="button" value="Preview" onclick="showPreview('EmailPreview');" />
</li>

<div id="dialog"> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 525,
                resizable: false,
                width: 600,
                dialogClass: 'timer'
            });
        });
      //]]>
    </script> 
</div>
```

In my .js file:

```
function showPreview(action, id) {
    $.get("/Manage/Account/" + action + "/" + id, function (data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#Area, #Exchange, #Number').autotab_magic().autotab_filter('numeric');
        $("#dialog input[type='button'], #dialog select,#dialog input:checkbox,#dialog input:radio,#dialog input:file").uniform();
    });
```

I use this exact code in 3 locations. In one location everything is perfectly functional. In the other 2 locations, done exactly they same, just in different views, the dialog box will open but not close. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

This is in the dialogbox-view:

```
 <div class="top"><a onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('close'); return false"><img src="/public/images/admin/btn-close.png" /></a></div>
```

Comment: You have tagged your questions incorrectly, this is jquery question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any dialog closing anywhere, you can close your dialog with this function:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

More about it: [jQueryUI dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

Also any element has to have unique ID, so it should be something like `#dialog-a`, `#dialog-b`, otherwise there will be errors with id selectors etc.

Comment: I just forgot to include that part. There is an "X" in the box that is supposed to close it. It works in one. I was wondering if there was a rule that I was breaking?

Comment: They open just fine, they just wont close

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog element IDs need to be unique, or jQuery won't find the right one.